# Simple - I can't access an object i've declared in Method A, within Method B

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

This is my code.

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        CGPoint boxPosition = CGPointMake(100,100);
        SKSpriteNode *box = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor colorWithRed:0.18 green:0.702 blue:0.91 alpha:0.5] size:CGSizeMake(35,25)];
        box.position = boxPosition;
        [self addChild:box]; 
    }
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(box.frame, touchPoint)) {
            // DO SOMETHING;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to access `box` in the `touchesBegan` method, but I can't. I'm really not sure why.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your .h file?

Comment: you need to read this article, this is not a tutorial site. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Variable_Scope_and_Storage_Class

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your variable is only in scope within `if (self = [super initWithSize:size])`. There are a couple of ways around this. You could do as the other answers suggest and create a property with which you can access the variable from anywhere with that instance of your class. Or, you could leverage `SKNode`'s `name` property:

```
SKSpriteNode *box = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor colorWithRed:0.18 green:0.702 blue:0.91 alpha:0.5] size:CGSizeMake(35,25)];
[box setName:@"aCoolName"];
```

Then you can use `SKNode`'s `childNodeWithName:` to get a reference to that child node within touches began.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKSpriteNode *box = (SKSpriteNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"aCoolName"];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(box.frame, touchPoint)) {
            //DO SOMETHING;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a local variable within the `initWithSize:` method (actually, local to the `if` block inside that method), so, after that method is complete the variable is not accessible. The created object has been added as a `child` so you could search for it...

You need to create an instance variable (`@property') and set that, then you can access it in any instance method. This could be in the .h file (of other classes need access to it), or in the .m file (in a continuation category preferably, if other classes don't need access).

Comment: Thanks so much!
Do I create that in the .h or .m?

Comment: The variable is not necessarily destroyed... he calls addChild:box... if that object is added to an array, it's definitely not destroyed.

Comment: @Merlevede The *variable* (i.e. `box`) is definitely destroyed, although the object it points to may not be, as you say.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths you're right, I should have used the word 'object' instead of 'variable'.

Answer (score 0):

definer SKSpriteNode *box in your *.h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) SKSpriteNode *box;
```

then use to access it in touchesBegan in your *.m file

```
@synthesize box
```

Your code in *.m will look like this.

```
box = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor colorWithRed:0.18 green:0.702 blue:0.91 alpha:0.5] size:CGSizeMake(35,25)];
```

or if you like you can define it in your *.h file as

```
@interface v1ViewController : UIViewController
{
   SKSpriteNode *box;
}
```

and then use it like

```
_box = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor colorWithRed:0.18 green:0.702 blue:0.91 alpha:0.5] size:CGSizeMake(35,25)];
```

Comment: Why are you recommending a `@property` and recommending he only access it via `_box` which ignores the setters and getters you're creating when you make a `@property`.  Why not just make an instance variable?  Moreover, why are you recommending he create a public `@property` in his `.h` file?  Does he need it outside this class?

Comment: I still don't understand why you're creating it publicly.  You just tell him that's how it needs to be done without addressing the difference between public and private.  Moreover, I still don't understand WHY you say to create a `@property` and then synthesize and only use the synthesized variable.  If you don't want to use the accessors that a `@property` creates for you, then don't use a property...